# Verifying Date stored in datetime format in mysql is less than current user input date with select command

Tags: mysql, sql, database, datetime

I have `validTo` column in mysql which is of `datetime` format, And i want to check if `date-time` stored in `validTo` column is less than `current date time` with just 1 `SELECT` command.

Something like :-

```
date_default_timezone_set("Asia/Calcutta");
$date = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');

$runQuery = $mysqli->query("SELECT pid from product where validTo < ".$mysqli->real_escape_string($date));
```

Above Statement is wrong, but is there any such thing which can help me accomplish my target **without fetching value** stored in **database**.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In MySQL you can use the NOW() function:

```
SELECT pid FROM product WHERE validTo < NOW();
```

In case you are interested in checking only the date (not the time):

```
SELECT pid FROM product WHERE DATE(validTo) < DATE(NOW());
```

and depending on your requirements you might need "<=" instead of just "<"